# TLP Charge Threshold Configuration on Lenovo IdeaPad

Tags: power-management, lenovo, battery, tlp

```
Kubuntu 23.04
Lenovo IdeaPad (not ThinkPad) 3 15ALC6
```

Hey, I'm trying to configure TLP to start charging when the battery reaches 50% and stop when it reaches 80%. I just want to make sure I'm doing everything correctly. Here's the comment in the **tlp.conf** file:

```
# Battery Care -- Charge thresholds
# Charging starts when the charge level is below the START_CHARGE_THRESH value
# when the charger is connected. It stops when the STOP_CHARGE_THRESH value is
# reached.
# Required hardware: Lenovo ThinkPads and select other laptop brands are driven
# via specific plugins, the actual support status is shown by tlp-stat -b.
# For more explanations and vendor specific details refer to
#   https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/battery.html
# Notes:
# - ThinkPads may require external kernel module(s), refer to the output of
#   tlp-stat -b
# - Vendor specific parameter value ranges are shown by tlp-stat -b
# - If your hardware supports a start *and* a stop threshold, you must
#   specify both, otherwise TLP will refuse to apply the single threshold
# - If your hardware supports only a stop threshold, set the start value to 0
```

The thing is, it's not very clear for me whether my device supports *"a start *and* a stop threshold."*

Here's the output of **tlp-stat -b**:

```
--- TLP 1.5.0 --------------------------------------------

+++ Battery Care
Plugin: lenovo
Supported features: charge threshold
Driver usage:
* vendor (ideapad_laptop) = active (charge threshold)
Parameter value range:
* STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0: 0(off), 1(on) -- battery conservation mode

/sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode = 0 (100%)

+++ Battery Status: BAT0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = SMP
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = L20M3PF0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    =    299
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  45000 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  43810 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  25460 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =   4556 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Discharging

Charge                                                      =   58.1 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   97.4 [%]
```